# Uniting two virtual environments/servers/apps into one (Nginx/Django)

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx

My project has two virtual environments, "main" and "test". I want to unite them on one server. I've been advised to use nginx proxy to do this, but I'm not sure how, especially since each environment already has its own network:

.yml backend of one project (infra/main folder) (the backend of the "test" project is similar):

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.3
    container_name: postgres_main
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_main:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    env_file:
      - .env-main
    networks:
      - main_db_network
  backend:
    <...>
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - .env-main
    networks:
      - main_db_network
      - main_swag_network
  migrations:
      <...>

networks:
  main_db_network:
    name: main_db_network
    external: true
  main_swag_network:
    name: main_swag_network
    external: true

volumes:
  postgres_data_main:
    name: postgres_data_main
  static_value_main:
    name: static_value_main
```

How do I set up a nginx_proxy to unite the two on one server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new service `nginx` - probably in a separate docker-compose file
**nginx.conf** will look like:

```
upstream main {
    server backend:8000;      # name of the service in compose file and opened port
}

upstream test {
    server test-backend:8000;
}

location /main {
    proxy_pass http://main;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

location /test{
    proxy_pass http://test;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Or instead of changing service names - you may differentiate ports. E.g. `main` to have mapping `8000:8000` and test e.g. `8001:8000`

**Dockerfile** for nginx:

```
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

**docker-compose.yml** for serving Nginx

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - main_swag_network
      - test_swag_network

networks:
    main_swag_network:
        external: true
    test_swag_network:
        external: true
```

It just need to serve nginx and have connections to both networks defined in `test` and `main` configs

Comment: What should the separate docker-compose file look like, anything to have in mind?

Comment: No need to add db_networks there? Anyway, I'll try it like that, thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, the docker-compose and the nginx.conf file can be in a separate directory of the infra folder and the project will pick them up automatically?

Comment: @MikhailTurkhan in my example `nginx.conf` is picked up by `Dockerfile` of nginx (which can be in any directory) and in compose file you specify directory of build (i.e. where Dockerfile is located) `db_networks` is not needed because nginx has to have access only to your app and not database

Comment: Now I understand it much better, one more clarification: what do the location /main and location /test signify in nginx.conf - the ultimate web addresses of the environments? Or are they located in proxy_pass parameters?

Comment: Or do location /main and location /test refer to folders?